# Comparison of id in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, article, sections

I have `section` and `article` for displaying contents. My code is:

```
<section id = "examples">

 <article id="item_1">
    ...
 </article>

 <article id="item_2">
  ...
 </article>

 <article id="item_3">
    ...
 </article>

 <article id="item_4">
  ...
 </article>

 ...

</section>
```

I am trying to get the id's of the `articles` so that I can compare, but I am getting undefined. My code is:

```
var compare = "item_1"

$('article').each(function(){
 var pos = $('article').id;
 console.log(pos) //getting undefined

    if( pos == compare)
     // do something

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` to get each article element's `id`: `var pos = this.id;`:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N49zr/1)

```
var compare = "item_1";

$('article').each(function () {
    var pos = this.id;
    console.log(pos);

    if (pos == compare) {
        alert('match');
    }

});
```

Output:

```
item_1
item_2
item_3
item_4
```